# Como adicionar 0 n frente de numeros menores que 9 para um timer?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um timer a para a função que escrevi, não estou conseguindo adicionar o 0 na frente dos numeros menores que 9. Ja tentei declarar dentro de timer():

```
if (seconds.innerText < 10) {
seconds.innerText = `0${seconds.innerText}`;
}
```

deu certo, mas no final, quando reseta o timer fica 15:000  ao invés de 15:00. Fiz a mesma coisa para minutos :

```
if (minutes.innerText < 10) {
minutes.innerText = `0${minutes.innerText}`;
}
```

mas quando aperto play, a partir de 9 min começa a acrescentar infinitos 0s ao invés de só 1. Será que conseguem ajudar? :)

```js
   
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");

  
var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");

var bell_meditate = new Audio("./midia/bell_meditate.mp3");


var startCountner;

function Start() {
  bell_meditate.play();
  if (startCountner === undefined) {
    startCountner = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    document.getElementById("daily-title").innerHTML = "Your daily";
    document.getElementById("daily-title").classList.add("daily-title");
    document.getElementById("meditation-title").innerHTML = "Meditation";
    document
      .getElementById("meditation-title")
      .classList.add("meditation-title");
    document.getElementById("pulse").style.animation =
      "pulse 4s infinite alternate";
  } else alert("Time is already running");
}

   
function Reset() {
  minutes.innerText = 15;
  seconds.innerText = "00";
  stopInterval();
  startCountner = undefined;
}

   
function timer() {
  if (seconds.innerText != 0) {
    seconds.innerText--;
  } else if (minutes.innerText != 0 && seconds.innerText == 0) {
    seconds.innerText = 59;
    minutes.innerText--;
  } else if (seconds.innerText == 0 && minutes.innerText == 0) {
    document.getElementById("daily-title").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("meditation-title").innerHTML = "Namastê";
    document
      .getElementById("meditation-title")
      .classList.add("message-namaste");
    audio();
    Reset();
  }
 
}

function audio() {
  bell_meditate.play();
}
  
function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(startCountner);
  document.getElementById("pulse").style.animation = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver isso você pode ao invés de utilizar strings nos minutos e segundos, utilizar numeros, e na hora de mostrar esses numeros converter pra string e adicionar o [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), onde você coloca `str.padStart(comprimentoDesejadoDaString, oQueVocêQuerAdicionar)`.

Se você colocar `2` no `comprimentoDesejadoDaString` a função vai preencher com `oQueVocêQuerAdicionar` até você ter `2` de comprimento.

O `oQueVocêQuerAdicionar` então é qualquer coisa que você queira preencher até chegar no `comprimentoDesejadoDaString`, se você colocar `0`, vai preencher com `0`'s, se você não colocar nada ele vai preencher com um espaço em branco ( ).

Quando você for diminuir os valores você transforma em string pra retornar pra tela.

```
...
function timer() {
  if (seconds.innerText != 0) {
     parseInt(seconds.innerText--);
     seconds.innerText = seconds.innerText.toString().padStart(2,'0');
  } else if (minutes.innerText != 0 && seconds.innerText == 0) {
    seconds.innerText = 59;
    parseInt(minutes.innerText--);
    minutes.innerText = minutes.innerText.toString().padStart(2,'0');
  }
   ...
}
```

Coloquei um exemplo rodando por console.log pra você ver, nesse exemplo eu não estou trocando nada no codigo, só no console.log que eu transformo em string. No seu caso seria no momento que você troca na tela. Assim como descrito acima.

```js
var minutes = 15;
var seconds = 0;

var startCountner;

function Start() {
    if (startCountner === undefined) {
        startCountner = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    } else alert("Time is already running");
}

function stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(startCountner);
}

function Reset() {
    minutes = 15;
    seconds = 0;
    stopInterval();
    startCountner = undefined;
}


function timer() {
    console.log(minutes.toString().padStart(2,'0'), seconds.toString().padStart(2,'0'))
    if (seconds != 0) {
        seconds--;
    } else if (minutes != 0 && seconds == 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes--;
    } else if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
        Reset();
    }

}

Start()
```

Comment: muito obrigada!! Eu consegui, ao final, fazer funcionar de outra maneira, mas ficou meio confuso. Eu não conhecia o padStart, ficou muito melhor! Obrigada!

Comment: @KelaW se vocè considera a resposta como valida marque ela como "soluçao" :)